# View will automatically move down while textview overlapping on a view

Tags: java, android, layout, textview, constraints

I want to create a chat bubbles like whatsapp. The problem is that constraints not working stable on code side. I have used onGlobalLayoutListener but in recyclerview view is changing when user scrolls. I've tried to show the situation as a pictures below there. If the text is short linearlayout will constraint end of textview. If it is long linearlayout will be move down. And if the second line of text is short linearlayout will constraints right of the textview.

[Short Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW6H4.png) [Long Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCBcn.png)

I want to make the layout as seen these ugly masterpieces. Thanks for attentions and helps.

I've tried onGlobalLayoutListener as on code-side but it doesnt work stable. In xml side i couldnt solve my problem.